# VBA - copy rows - if it found error, then continue in copy cells

Tags: vba, excel, copy, copy-paste

I have macro which copy cells to below's cells.

```
Sub CopyRows2()

Dim LastRow As Long

With Worksheets("Ready to upload") ' <-- here should be the Sheet's name
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "AD").End(xlUp).Row ' last row in column C

For i = 2 To LastRow
If Range("AD" & i) > "" And Range("AD" & i + 1) = "" Then
    Range("AD" & i).Copy
    Range("AD" & i + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

Else

    End If
Next

End With

ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1 'scrolling the screen to the top

End Sub
```

It works fine, until it will found `#N/A`, then it will give me an error msg: **Run-time error '13' - type mismatch**. In that case, I would like to skip it and then continue in copy rows.

[[image]

Could you advise me, how to do that, please?

Many thanks!

Comment: Hint: (Not related to the error): You should use `.Range` instead of `Range` else you are accessing the active sheet and not the sheet of the `With`-statement

Comment: Yes, you are right! It has showed me an error msg and I didnt know why and that was the trigger. I've accidentally removed those dots :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1**

The easiest way is to embed `On Error Resume Next` in your code. Then it will work.

---

**Option 2**
If you want to be one step more professional, then you can use something like this:

```
Sub CopyRows2()

    Dim LastRow As Long

    On Error Resume Next

    'your code

    If Err.Number = 13 Then Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

It will disregard error `13`, but it will tell you if there are other errors, which is quite useful.

---

**Option 3** Check for error like this:

```
If Not IsError(Range("AD" & i)) And Not IsError(Range("AD" & i + 1)) Then
    'embed the code here
End If
```